# Tracking events on Google Analytics via plain HTTP POST request

Tags: http, google-analytics, http-post

I want to track custom events via Google Analytics. Looks like GA's "events" should fit my task. I'm composing the request according to [this manual](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#event). 
I'm watching for the result on my web Analytics page -> Behavior -> Events.

This is the request I ended up with:

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-00000000-1&cid=a18f0e1b-0500-459b-8b85-e2f44f77bf56&t=event&ec=Image&ea=display&el=abcd1234&ev=11213418
```

Here I've edited out my UA, obviously I actually use the real one. This request returns HTTP 200 OK and seems to also return a tiny GIF in its data, but the event is not tracked in the Events Overview. So, I'm thinking it's one of the 3:
1. This request is wrong, I can't get away with simply passing all the parameters via the URL.
2. I'm watching for the result in the wrong place.
3. I need to setup my GA account somehow, other than simply specifying some website and not actually embedding the regular GA scripts anywhere (I've just set this GA account up).

What might my problem be?

Comment: Use Real Time Analytics to test events. It takes time (up to 1-2 day) to show events in general reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested you link and it is showing up in the reports for me

In GA go to Real-Time > Events

[image]

Comment: All right, thanks! So this way of posting works, and I just need to find a way to post persistent events rather than real time (these are lost once they go out of the time scope). Would you happen to know the name of the GA facility that I need for persistent tracking and counting of custom events?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe how do you know they're lost? Are you aware that hits sent to GA sometimes take 24-48 hours before they appear in reports?